# validation on client side javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Im working on simple project using asp.net and I have created a form in which the user could upload a file. before storing the data on client side I made workaround to check file extension and stop postback if the file not image

```js
function checkFileExtention() {
            
var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value;
var lastIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
var fileExt = file.substr(lastIndex + 1).toLowerCase();

            var isValidExtention=0;
            var i;
            var extArray = ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"];
           
            for (i = 0; i < extArray.Length; i++) {
                
                if (fileExt == extArray[i]) {

                    isValidExtention = 1;
                    return true;
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "invalid";
                    return false;
                    isValidExtention = 0;
                }


            }
         
            
        }
```

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="addButton" runat="server" type="submit" CausesValidation="true" 
OnClick="addButton_Click" OnClientClick="if (!checkFileExtention()) {return false;}">Add</asp:LinkButton>
```

but i faced some issues where I can't show alert or set text inside for loop 
even value of variable isValidExtention  always 0 outside the loop

any help would be appreciated

Comment: *isValidExtention always 0 outside the loop* what does this mean? You never use `isValidExtention` anywhere so how do you know it's *always 0*? Why do you need this integer at all if you return a boolean and use that? Every time you call `checkFileExtention` this is going to get reset to zero as it is declared in the function (`var isValidExtention=0;`). All in all this question is very unclear and needs a lot of clarification/a clear problem statement.

Comment: `if (!checkFileExtention()) {return false;}` should just be `return checkFileExtention()`. I **think** this might be your issue because there is no way for this to return `true` currently. All the above is still relevant though.

Comment: are you getting file using this line var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value; ?

Comment: @Liam I tried several to debug the code in and out side the loop because I can't show alert nor set text value , I used isValidExtention to check file size later .BTW , I change it to return checkFileExtention() still not working

Comment: Arrays have a method named `includes()` that will return true if a certain element exists inside an array. So `return ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"].includes(file.substr(lastIndex + 1).toLowerCase())` will almost be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only problem in you code is little mistake like you are using "Length" instead of length. I modified your code please take a look.

```
function checkFileExtention() {
        var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value;
        var lastIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
        var fileExt = file.substr(lastIndex + 1).toLowerCase();

        var isValidExtention = false;
        var i;
        var extArray = ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"];
        for (i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {
            if (fileExt == extArray[i]) {
                isValidExtention = true;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "";
                break;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "invalid";
            }
        }
        return isValidExtention;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
function checkFileExtention() {
       var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value;
        if (file != "") {
            var fileExt  = file.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
             var isValidExtention=0;
            var i;
            var extArray = ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"];

        for (i = 0; i < extArray.Length; i++) {

            if (fileExt.toLowerCase() == extArray[i]) {

                isValidExtention = 1;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "";                   
                break;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "invalid";
                isValidExtention = 0;                   

            }
    }
});
```

Second way to check file extension,

```
function checkFileExtention() {
       var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value;
        if (file != "") {
            var ext = file.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
            var isValidExtention=0;
            ext.toLowerCase();
            if (ext == "png" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext=="gif") {
                isValidExtention = 1;
                    return true;                   
            }
            else {
               document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "invalid";
               isValidExtention = 0;
               return false;

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you I just replaced for loop with if statement and it's working but it's not practical way . why I can't show alert nor set text inside loop if statements ??

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the below code. we restrict before upload file file is image or not..

```
   var oFileIn = document.getElementById('fileupload');        
    if (oFileIn.addEventListener) {
        oFileIn.addEventListener('change', filePicked, false);
    }

    function filePicked(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$");
    if (!(regex.test(files[0].name)))
    {
        alert('Please select image files');
        var oFileIn = document.getElementById('fileupload');
        oFileIn.value='';
        return;
    }

    }
```

I hope its helpful to you.

Thanks and regards
Angappan.S

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
const regex = /.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\s*$/mig;
const str = `image.jpg
image.notmatching
capitalLetterFormat.PNG
.jpg
`;
```

it checks the following:

1. the image format matches your format
2. ignores possible spaces added at the end of your image
3. formats the name of your image is not empty.
4. the format is not case sensitive